# SMPS Control Loops - How do I calculate the modulator transconductance?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

Referring to [SMPS Compensation Made Eas](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup340/slup340.pdf)y - how do I calculate Gm(Mod)?

[image]

Looking through the application note, I found this equation (I think it's the right one?), but now I am not sure what A and Rs are, any help?

[image]

Comment: Can you determine the gain (\$R_i\$) of the current monitoring transimpedance amplifier shown in 38?

Comment: \$R_i\$ usually refers to the sense resistance in a current-mode power supply. This is Ridley's terminology. Now, if you associate a sense resistance \$R_s\$ with an amplifier of gain \$A\$, then the equivalent sense resistance \$R_i\$ becomes \$AR_s\$.

Comment: Yes, and how do I figure out what those values of Rs and A are?

Comment: @RGBEngineer They are based on your specific circuit design choices (E.g. your chosen sense resistor and controller IC.)